# Debian vs Mint?

Tags: debian, linux-mint

I can't decide whether to choose Debian or Linux Mint for my first distribution.

Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu (if I understood right), and Ubuntu is based on Debian. But as I saw Ubutnu is really slow when works at booting has long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is "primarily opinion based", but I do want to clear up some possible confusion:

> as I saw Ubutnu is really slow when works at booting has long time.

I'm not sure where you get that information.  If it's experiential based on using a liveCD, the liveCD's are very slow (all of them).

If it's based on web gossip, **it's misinformation.**  Mint vs. Ubuntu vs. Fedora vs. Whatever-Distro-You-Like will have approximately the same boot times for the same software stack (the "software stack" includes your choice of desktop environment -- GNOME, KDE, Cinnamon, etc.)<sup>1</sup>

The init daemon used may make a slight difference; the one used by Debian is perhaps the slowest (note that the one used by Ubuntu is not the same), but for normal personal computers this will only amount to a few seconds.

On a reasonably beefy (2.0 Ghz +) multi-core system the time from bootloader menu to GUI login should be < 30 seconds; on my 3.4 Ghz quad-core i5 w/ ssd it's ~5 seconds sans GUI.  This is regardless of distro.

<sup>1</sup> The most significant differences in user experience between one standalone GUI linux system and another are *because of the desktop environment (DE)* and not because of the distro.  I.e, if you use KDE on Ubuntu, your experience will be more like a Fedora system running KDE than another Ubuntu system running GNOME.  Mint, like a few other distros, has some DE options unique to it, so those can't be compared of course.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you are new to linux, Linux Mint would be the way to go.

As far as tinkering with it goes, no matter what linux distro you choose, the ability to tinker with it is always there. The difference is how much the distro requires from you to **do** to setup/install it, how much it requires from you to **know** to tinker with it and what it provides **by default**. In the end, the command line (CLI) is the only toolset you really need and it's always there.

Now, Debian provides only FOSS by default (i.e Flash won't be what you expect, Firefox is rebranded as Iceweasel, etc) and often requires from you to open a terminal to do the job . Linux Mint provides all the software you would expect to be installed in a free (free as in $0 price, not as in free software) OS and more GUI tools to tweak the system.

In general, Linux Mint is friendlier and more appealing to the newcomer, but since it is a Debian-based distro the underlying system is more or less the same with Debian.

Personally, I am a Debian fan.